# Concatenate Values inside a data frame in R

Tags: r

I have two data frame

```
> data1
  LEVEL V1 V2
1    L1  a  c
2    L2  b  d
> data2
  LEVEL V1 V2
1    L1  1  3
2    L2  2  4
```

How can I create a third data frame

```
> data3
  LEVEL  V1  V2
1    L1 a_1 c_3
2    L2 b_2 d_4
```

Preferably using dplyr/tidyr in R

Comment: This looks like you'd need to prep the data with some renaming, do ` left_join`, and then some `mutate`s (and `paste`). What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `rbind.data.frame` and then `summarise_all` per `LEVEL`

```
data <- rbind.data.frame(data1, data2) # rbind data frames
data %>%
        group_by(LEVEL) %>%
        summarise_all(paste, collapse = "_")
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  LEVEL    V1    V2
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1    L1   a_1   c_3
2    L2   b_2   d_4
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option using `mapply`

```
data.frame(data1[, 1, drop = FALSE],
           mapply(FUN = paste, MoreArgs = list(sep = "_"), data1[,-1], data2[,-1]))
#  LEVEL  V1  V2
#1    L1 a_1 c_3
#2    L2 b_2 d_4
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
bind_cols(data2[, 1, drop = FALSE],
          map2_df(.x = data1[, -1], .y = data2[, -1], .f = paste, sep = "_"))
#  LEVEL  V1  V2
#1    L1 a_1 c_3
#2    L2 b_2 d_4
```

**data**

```
data1 <- read.table(text = "
LEVEL V1 V2
1    L1  a  c
2    L2  b  d", header = TRUE)

data2 <- read.table(text = "
LEVEL V1 V2
1    L1  1  3
2    L2  2  4", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, I assume that you want to use `LEVEL` as a key to match the two tables and that you don't have too many variables to deal with.

```
df3 <- left_join(df1, df2, by="LEVEL")%>%
  mutate(a=paste(a.x, a.y, sep="_"), b=paste(b.x, b.y, sep="_")) %>%
  select_if(grepl("\\.", colnames(df3)) ==FALSE)
```